# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, tripledes, javax.crypto

I'm using Triple DES for my encryption/decryption purpose but somehow it gives me above exception and I tried other approaches as well mentioned in the related answers, but I'm stuck. I'm new to cryptography and corresponding java libs.

```
private static byte[] Key = new byte[] {
        0x42, 0x45, 0x49, 0x30, 0x12, 0x22, 0x35, 0x48, 0x33, 0x24, 0x28, 0x51,
        0x48, 0x24, 0x30, 0x21, 0x44, 0x31, 0x14, 0x19, 0x45, 0x34, 0x47, 0x25 };

Cipher c;

public EncryptionHelper() throws Exception {
    // byte[] key_hash = (Key).toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    // key_hash = Arrays.copyOf(key_hash, 32);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Key, 0, Key.length, "DESede");
    c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
}

public String Encrypt(String S) throws Exception {
    byte[] base64EncryptedText = S.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte EncryptedText[] = c.doFinal(base64EncryptedText, 0, base64EncryptedText.length);
    return new String(EncryptedText);
}

public String Decrypt(String S) throws Exception {
    Cipher c2 = null;
    // byte[] key_hash = (Key).toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    // key_hash = Arrays.copyOf(key_hash, 24);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Key,0, Key.length, "DESede");
    c2 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] base64EncryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encode(S.getBytes());
    byte[] textDecrypted = c2.doFinal(base64EncryptedText, 0, base64EncryptedText.length);
    return new String(textDecrypted, "UTF-8");
}
```

EDIT:

Finally worked through the solution, I was just misplacing the components, specified the core logic as well.

```
public class EncryptionHelper {

private static byte[] Key = new byte[] {
    0x42, 0x45, 0x49, 0x30, 0x12, 0x22, 0x35, 0x48, 0x33, 0x24, 0x28, 0x51,
    0x48, 0x24, 0x30, 0x21, 0x44, 0x31, 0x14, 0x19, 0x45, 0x34, 0x47, 0x25 };

static Cipher c;

public EncryptionHelper() throws Exception {
    // byte[] key_hash = (Key).toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    // key_hash = Arrays.copyOf(key_hash, 32);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Key, 0, Key.length, "DESede");
    c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
}

public static String Encrypt(String S) throws Exception {
    byte[] base64EncryptedText = S.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte EncryptedText[] = c.doFinal(base64EncryptedText, 0, base64EncryptedText.length);
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(EncryptedText));
}

// LOGIC:
// for encryption: string -> utf-8 byte array,
        // encrypt and return a base 64 encoded string
// for decryption: String -> base64 -> decode base 64 array,
        // decrypt and return utf-8 string

public static String Decrypt(String S) throws Exception {
    Cipher c2 = null;
    // byte[] key_hash = (Key).toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    // key_hash = Arrays.copyOf(key_hash, 24);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Key, "DESede");
    c2 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] base64EncryptedText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(S.getBytes());
    byte[] textDecrypted = c2.doFinal(base64EncryptedText, 0, base64EncryptedText.length);
    return new String(textDecrypted, "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the names on your variables you have failed to base64-encode the result of encryption in your `Encrypt` method. Therefore, when you convert it to String you get garbage, and when you base64 decode that garbage in your `Decrypt` method you get garbage<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You are base64-decoding and then decrypting, but you are not encrypting and then base64-encoding.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer!

Comment: @Yahya You are mistaken. It is an answer, not a comment. It identifies the problem in the OP's code. It says exactly the same thing as the answer that you identified as correct.